# Count on which loop text was entered and display as index

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a small program which takes a text input - and then places each of these items in a dictionary alongside which line they were entered on. At the moment if I enter 4 lines of text. It'll take them all out correctly, but every word will be set to the value 4 - instead of the loop it was inputted on. I've removed all the other functions from my code (remove punct, remove stopwords, stemwords, etc). to make this clearer.

```
from string import *

function = False
words_split = []
lineNumber=0
final_value = []

def indexer(t):
    global words_split
    words = t.split();
    for word in words:
        words_split.append(word)

def dict_print():
    for keys in Dict:
            output = keys + " " + str(Dict[keys][0])
            i= 1
            while i < len(Dict[keys]):
                output = output + ", " + str(Dict[keys][i])
                i = i + 1
            print(output)

print("Please type a line and hit 'Enter' or type a single fullstop followed by 'Enter' to exit \n")
text = ""
while function == False :
    if(text == "."):
        print("The index is:")
        function = True
        dict_print()

    else:
        Dict = {}
        text = input()
        lineNumber += 1
        for word in words_split:
            if word in Dict:
                if lineNumber not in Dict[word]:
                    Dict[word] = Dict[word] + [lineNumber]
            else:
                Dict[word] = [lineNumber]
        indexer(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

My global variable was causing the issue. I'll leave this up with my completed full code in case someone else runs into the same issue (:

https://repl.it/@Glaschu/AdmiredSteelCardinal